# OneToMany relation not load collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class `Traveller` with a relationship with `TravellerVote`. I wish retrieve the sending votes the travellers and the votes received.

**Class Traveller**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id")
public class Traveller extends User{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="voter", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,  CascadeType.REMOVE})
    protected List<TravellerVote> myVotes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="partner", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,  CascadeType.REMOVE})
    protected List<TravellerVote> receivedVotes;

    public Traveller(){
        super();
        myVotes = new ArrayList<TravellerVote>();
        receivedVotes = new ArrayList<TravellerVote>();
    }

    public void addVote(TravellerVote vote){
        myVotes.add(vote);
    }
}
```

**Class TravellerVote**

```
@Entity
public class TravellerVote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length=11)
    protected long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="voter_id")
    protected Traveller voter;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="partner_id")
    protected Traveller partner;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    protected Date date;

    @Column(length=300, nullable=true)
    protected String comment;

    @Column(nullable=false)

    protected boolean positive;
        public TravellerVote(Traveller voter, Traveller partner, String comment, boolean positive){
        this.date = new Date();
        this.voter = voter;
        this.partner = partner;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.positive = positive;   
    }
}
```

The entities are persisted correctly in the database, with this:

```
TravellerDao dao = new TravellerDao();
Traveller t1 = dao.findByUsername("ramiromd");
Traveller t2 = dao.findByUsername("danimd");
Traveller t3 = dao.findByUsername("famartinezd");

t1.addVote(new TravellerVote(t1, t2, "Test comment", true));
t2.addVote(new TravellerVote(t2, t1, "Test comment", true));
t3.addVote(new TravellerVote(t3, t1, "Test comment", false));

dao.save(t1);
dao.save(t2);
dao.save(t3);
```

[image: TravellerVote after save entities]

But, when in other controller try get the votes, the collections have 0 elements.

```
TravellerDao dao = new TravellerDao();
Traveller t1 = dao.findByUsername("ramiromd");
t1.getReceivedVotes().size(); // Must be 2 not 0.
t1.getMyVotes().size(); // Must be 1 not 0.
```

The TravellerDao save method:

```
public void save(Traveller traveller) {
    EntityManager em = PersistenceHelper.getEm();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(traveller);
    //em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

It is the findByUsername method:

```
public Traveller findByUsername(String username){

    EntityManager em = PersistenceHelper.getEm();
    String qstring = "SELECT t FROM Traveller  t WHERE t.username LIKE :username";
    TypedQuery<Traveller> query = em.createQuery(qstring, Traveller.class);
    query.setParameter("username", username);


    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: flush() is pointless, it happens in commit. You haven't added anything to receivedVotes at any point (set it at both sides of the relation).

Comment: Ok, i remove the flush() line, now only have the transaction. But the collections are not populated when i fetch the traveller.

Comment: errm, where is "fetch the traveller" code? Is it persisted correctly in the datastore first? no point fetching it if it isn't persisted as you intended. If that is already correct then remove stuff about persisting from the question and show the bit that matters. And the log says what when you "fetch" it?

Comment: The "fetch traveller" code is `dao.findByUsername()`. Read my post.

Comment: Yes I know it is, and I can't see the code of that method.

Comment: I append the method in the post.

Answer (score 1):

In these scenarios , it is helpful to enable debugging for implementation framework. For example , if you are using Hibernate , set the debug level of org.hibernate package to "DEBUG". That will show you all SQLs being fired. In your problem , if you set fetch equal to LAZY , you will see exact SQLs being fired for these statements :-

```
t1.getReceivedVotes().size(); // Must be 2 not 0.
t1.getMyVotes().size();
```

Hopefully ,that will give you enough hint to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your dao save() method looks like but is there:

```
getEntityManager().flush();
```

?

If no please add after persist and check whether it helped.

Comment: Yes, i am using flush().

Comment: what container do you use? what is your persistence provider?

Comment: and only for test purpose could you add fetch = FetchType.EAGER to @OneToMany annotation in your entities and check if it changes the beheviour?

Comment: I put the fetch type but is the same result. I am using javax.persistence.*

Comment: javax.persistence.* is API - I'm asking about implementation(Hibernate, EclipseLink..). Do you execute your code in java SE application or in a container like tomcat/jboss?

Comment: Oh sory, i am newest in Java. Im using Hibernate, and run the code with JUnit.

Comment: JUnit is unit test framework. I would recommend not to run database code inside tests. Could you post the entire code of execution (save and find)? Also describe how you launch your code Anyway, could you change cascade to ALL and try? It may not help but in this specific setup it somehow misses to merge object.. Could you please provide also persistence.xml file?

Comment: @rebello95 what do you mean by "this". The above comment or the answer? I tried to answer the question. Code provided by the author was not sufficient so in a comment to my answer I ask for clarification. As I understood you ask me to stop because of my insufficient reputation?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Max I do not have any question that is not related to the question asked above. I asked for clarification in order to gain more information about the stated problem. You want me to ask for clarification in a separate question?

Comment: @iku if you want to ask for clarification on this question, then you should do so in a comment rather than an answer.